# How to get the xml WITHOUT escape characters? (javascript, angular)

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I'm pretty new in the javascript world. So bear with me. :-)

User press button "Save Customer Orders" (that will download a xml file to users pc):

orders.component.html:

```
... 
    <form (ngSubmit)="saveOrdersAsXml()" novalidate>
...
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Save Customer Orders</button> 
    </div>
...
```

The problem is: How to get the xml WITHOUT escape characters?:

orders.component.ts:

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit 
{
    ...

    private saveOrdersAsXml($event) 
    {
        this.orderService.GetOrdersAsXml(this.customerNumber)
            .subscribe(res => 
            {
                // res = "Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:52511/..."
                // res._body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>..."      
                // _body contains the xml. How do I get the xml without escape characters??

                let xml: string = res;
                const file = new Blob([xml], { type: 'text/xml;charset=utf-8' }); 
                saveAs(file, this.customerNumber + '.xml'); // Currently the file will contain "Response with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:52511/..." - I need it to be xml.
            }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

orders.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService 
{
    ...

    public GetOrdersAsXml(customerNumber: string): Observable<any> 
    {
        const dataResult = this._http.get("http://localhost:52511/api/orders/getordersasxml/" + customerNumber, , this.authenticationService.jwt()))
            .map((response: Response) => response)
            .catch(this.handleError);
        return dataResult;
    }
}
```

OrdersController.cs:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/orders")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpGet("getordersasxml/{customerNumber}")]
    public string GetOrdersAsXml(string customerNumber)
    {
        // Here the xml is fine (e.g.: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...")
        return _orderBL.GetOrdersAsXml(customerNumber);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
After **5 hours** of work I still don't get it.

I have tried to return JObject, HttpResponseMessage, byte[] and xDocument. It is getting frustrating...

When I use xDocument like this:

```
[HttpGet("getordersasxml/{customerNumber}")]
public XDocument GetOrdersAsXml(string customerNumber)
{
    // Here the xml is fine (e.g.: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...")
    var xml = _orderBL.GetOrdersAsXml(customerNumber);
    return XDocument.Parse(xml);
}
```

And in frontend I do this:

```
private saveOrdersAsXml($event) 
{
    this.orderService.GetOrdersAsXml(this.customerNumber)
        .subscribe(res => 
        {
            console.log("1: " + xmlResult);
            console.log("2: " + xmlResult._body);
            console.log("3: " + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlResult._body));

            ...
        }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

The console returns this:

1: Response with status: 200 OK for URL...

2:{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"utf-16"},"Customer"...

ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at SafeSubscriber.searchService.GetXMLFile.subscribe._this.errorMessage [as _next] (license.component.ts:111)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:254)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:204)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:135)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1259)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:3913)

Why is it so defficuelt to do such a simple task as sending an xml string from backend to frontend?!

I'm going to the dentist now, but will be back later. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you returning a `string` in your server-side code? I mean you can, but you could also return an `XDocument`. That will validate the document which is helpful. Also,  `.map((response: Response) => response)` does nothing at all. Have you tried `.map(response => response.blob())`?

Comment: `let xml: string = res._body` perhaps? seeing as you state that `res._body` contains the XML

Comment: @JaromandaX The problem by doing this is that _body is escaped.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks. I will try to go in this direction. Will post my result soon.

Comment: @mith7 You've shown us a lot of stuff, but not an example of how the XML is escaped. In what way is it escaped?

Comment: @JLRishe. Like this: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>..." (see code also). But I found a solution. See my own anwer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Apparently a trip to the dentist helped ;-)

I did this:

OrdersController.cs:

```
[HttpGet("getordersasxml/{customerNumber}")]
public string GetOrdersAsXml(string customerNumber)
{
    //return _orderBL.GetOrdersAsXml(customerNumber); // Gives trouble!

    // Put xml as a byte array into a json
    var xml = _orderBL.GetOrdersAsXml(customerNumber);
    var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)
    }); 
    return response;
}
```

orders.component.ts:

```
private saveOrdersAsXml($event) 
{
    this.orderService.GetOrdersAsXml(this.customerNumber)
        .subscribe(res => 
        {
            // let xml: string = res; // Won't work

            // Parse json-string to json object and convert the data byte array to a string.
            let xml:string = atob(JSON.parse(res).data); 

            const file = new Blob([xml], { type: 'text/xml;charset=utf-8' }); 
            saveAs(file, this.customerNumber + '.xml'); 
        }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Hope someone finds this helpful. :-)